# Pandas Dataframe Sorting by Date Time

Tags: python, pandas

whenever I run
`print(dfsamen.sort_values(['DateTime']))`
 my code works fine and the date is properly sorted and looks like this:
`2018-08-31 00:00:02`
`2018-08-31 00:00:12`
`2018-08-31 00:00:22`
`2018-08-31 00:00:32`

but when I do it this way (I want it this way so I can do calculations, i know i can write it to csv and then load it back in but that seems redundant)

`dfsamen.sort_values(by=['DateTime'])
print(dfsamen)`

this is the output (like it is in the excel file)
`2018-08-31 03:54:10`
`2018-08-31 03:54:20`
`2018-08-31 03:48:52`

I also tried this:

`dfsamen.reset_index()`
`dfsamen.set_index(['DateTime'])`
`dfsamen.sort_index(inplace=True)`

which resulted in the same outcome.

Comment: Need assign back by `dfsamen = dfsamen.sort_values(by=['DateTime'])`

Comment: Use the ```inplace``` attribute and make it ```True```

Comment: Zzzzz...... Thanks, ive been up for too long.